# why the volume of sounds does not change in my app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I used code below in my application, and if I increase or decrease the volume from the iPhone's button it's still the same, but if the phone is in silent mode the voice will be muted.

The code:

```
-(void) playNote: (NSString *)Note type: (NSString *)type
{
    CFURLRef        soundFileURLRef;
    SystemSoundID   soundFileObject;
    CFBundleRef mainBundle;
    mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle ();

// Get the URL to the sound file to play
soundFileURLRef  =  CFBundleCopyResourceURL (mainBundle,
         (CFStringRef)Note,
         (CFStringRef)type,
         NULL);


NSLog(@"%@\n", soundFileURLRef);
    // Create a system sound object representing the sound file
        AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID (soundFileURLRef, &soundFileObject);

   AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (soundFileObject);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi, I was wondering if you ever figured out an answer to this problem because I'm having the same one?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your Audio Category properly before playing back sounds.

```
UInt32 sessionCategory = kAudioSessionCategory_MediaPlayback;
AudioSessionSetProperty (kAudioSessionProperty_AudioCategory, sizeof (sessionCategory), &sessionCategory);
```

Comment: Well, at least before playing your sound. Not sure if it will compile directly like this. But you can also take a look at the AudioSession reference.